# Display list view on click of Search Bar

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, searchview

I have created a custom Search Bar. I want to display a simple list view right on click of Search Bar. The searchBar.onClickListener() doesn't work in this case. It doesn't get called at all. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Try this https://abhiandroid.com/ui/searchview

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`?

```
search_view.setOnQueryTextListener(this)

override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
    // Do something here

    return false
}

override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
    // do something here 

    return false
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
search_view.setOnSearchClickListener({
    // Show list
})
```

Comment: Yes I have already done that. I just want to display my list view on click of Search Bar.

Comment: Have you implemented setOnSearchClickListener?

Answer (score 0):

If you have searchview, and want click of it, you can click on Search icon and perform the tasks you want to, but if you don't want to show keyboard, there's other option to take EditText with drawable left as you Search icon and perform your tasks you want to.. If you are still unable to resolve it, just let me know to create a chat..